# How to check reference when inserting in MongoDB (typegraphql, typegoose)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

Let say I have a simple collection `events` created by TypeGraphql and Typegoose which stores objects like:

`{ _id: ObjectId(...), name: 'SomeEvent', category: ObjectId('...') }`

and corresponding type:

```
@ObjectType()
export class Event {
  @Field(() => ID)
  _id!: Types.ObjectId

  @prop({ ref: 'Category' })
  @Field(() => Category)
  category!: Ref<Category>

  @prop()
  @Field()
  name!: string
}
```

I have also collection `categories` which contains right now only `_id` and `name`.

Now I want to insert some Event to database. Is it possible to automatically check if categoryId provided in input exist in collection `categories` and if it does not, throw an error? Right now, event can be added with anything in `category` field and next when I try to get it by query it throws an error that `category` cannot be resolved because there is no category with this ID. I know, that I can check it manually during adding event but if I have more fields like that it will be problematic.

Answer (score 4):

With the help of Martin Devillers answer I was able to write a validator to validate referenced documents using class-validator with typegoose.

This is my refdoc.validator.ts:

```
import { ValidationArguments, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface } from "class-validator";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { getModelForClass } from "@typegoose/typegoose";


@ValidatorConstraint({ name: "RefDoc", async: true })
@Injectable()
export class RefDocValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

    async validate(refId: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const modelClass = args.constraints[0];
        return getModelForClass(modelClass).exists({ _id: refId })
    }

    defaultMessage(): string {
        return "Referenced Document not found!";
    }
}
```

Then I can apply it on the DTO or model with the @Validate-Decorator. The Argument I'm passing in is the typegoose model.

```
@Validate(RefDocValidator, [Costcenter])
costcenterId: string;
```

Seems to be working for me, I'm open for any improvements..

**Edit: Even better with custom decorator, as Martin Devillers suggested:**

refdoc.validator.ts

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationArguments, ValidationOptions, ValidatorConstraint, ValidatorConstraintInterface } from "class-validator";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { getModelForClass } from "@typegoose/typegoose";


@ValidatorConstraint({ name: "RefDoc", async: true })
@Injectable()
export class RefDocValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {

    async validate(refId: string, args: ValidationArguments) {
        const modelClass = args.constraints[0];
        return getModelForClass(modelClass).exists({ _id: refId })
    }

    defaultMessage(): string {
        return "Referenced Document not found!";
    }
}

export function RefDocExists(modelClass: any, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: 'RefDocExists',
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [modelClass],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: RefDocValidator,
        });
    };
}
```

Then you can use it on the DTO like:

```
@ApiProperty()
@IsNotEmpty()
//@Validate(RefDocValidator, [Costcenter]) old
@RefDocExists(Costcenter) //new
costcenterId: string;
```

Comment: Nice job, this is pretty nifty! I think if you register the validator with `class-validator` you can use a cleaner annotation like `@IsValidReference()` I found an example of someone doing this on GitHub here: https://github.com/khaledafify/Rayah/blob/183d488ec63b6e063787dffb97e3aa1933c309ed/server/src/shared/validators/category/category-exists.validator.ts

Comment: Thank you, very good idea! Edited this in. Looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, neither MongoDB nor mongoose nor typegoose offer any automated [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) checks.

At the database level, this feature doesn't exist (which is also one of the fundamental differences between a database like MongoDB and SQL Server/Oracle).

However, at the application level, you can achieve this behavior in various ways:

1. **Middleware**. Mongoose middleware allows you add generalized behavior to your models. This is useful if you're inserting documents in your `EventModel` in various places in your codebase and don't want to repeat your validation logic. For example:

```
EventModel.path('category').validate(async (value, respond) => {
    const categoryExists = await CategoryModel.exists({ _id: value })
    respond(categoryExists)
})
```

2. **Mongoose plugins**. A plugin like [mongoose-id-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-id-validator) allows you to add the above behavior to any type of document reference in all your schemas.
3. **Manually**. Probably the least favorite option, but I'm mentioning it for completeness sake: with mongoose's [Model.exists()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.exists) you can achieve this with a one-liner like: `const categoryExists = await CategoryModel.exists({ _id: event.category })`

To reiterate: all the above options are stopgaps. It's always possible for someone to go directly in your database and break referential integrity anyway.

Comment: Any idea how you would apply method 1 in typegoose? With pre-hooks?